# C - Allocate a struct within a function using the struct pointer as argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, ruby-c-extension

I am working with the Ruby C API. I need to create a struct from within a function but I think I am making some allocation error. This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ruby.h>
#include <ruby/thread.h>

typedef struct {
    double *matrix;
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
}Matrix;


void createMatrix(VALUE matrix, Matrix *mat) {
    printf("In\n");
    mat->nrows = RARRAY_LEN(matrix);
    VALUE firstElement = rb_ary_entry(matrix, 0);
    mat->ncols = RARRAY_LEN(firstElement);
    printf("Matrix shape: (%d,%d)\n", mat->nrows, mat->ncols);
    int i,j;

    double *tempMat = (double *)malloc(mat->nrows * mat->ncols * sizeof(double));

    printf("Allocated\n");
    VALUE row;
    for (i=0; i<mat->nrows; i++)
    {
        row = rb_ary_entry(matrix, i);
        for (j=0; j<mat->ncols; j++)
        {
            tempMat[i * mat->ncols + j] = NUM2DBL(rb_ary_entry(row, j));
//          printf("Matrix A Element(%d,%d)=%f\n", i, j, matA[i * colsA + j]);
        }
    }
    mat->matrix = tempMat;
    for (i=0; i<mat->nrows; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<mat->ncols; j++)
            {
                printf("Matrix temp Element(%d,%d)=%f\n", i, j, mat->matrix[i * mat->ncols + j]);
            }
        }

    printf("Assigned\n");
    return;
}


VALUE matmat_mul(VALUE self, VALUE matrixA, VALUE matrixB)
{
    int i,j;

    Matrix *matA;
    createMatrix(matrixA, matA);

    Matrix *matB;
    createMatrix(matrixB, matB);

    return Qnil;
}

void Init_la_ruby_ext()
{
    VALUE rg = rb_define_module("RG");
    VALUE linalg = rb_define_module_under(rg, "LinearAlgebra");
    VALUE operation = rb_define_class_under(linalg, "Operation", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_method(operation, "matmat_mul", matmat_mul, 2);
}
```

The `extconf.rb` file is

```
require 'mkmf'
extension_name = 'la_ruby_ext'
create_makefile(extension_name)
```

and you can run the test with

```
require './la_ruby_ext'
rows = 3
cols = 3
mat = Array.new(rows){Array.new(cols)}
mat[0] = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
mat[1] = [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
mat[2] = [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
operation = RG::LinearAlgebra::Operation.new 
matC = operation.matmat_mul(mat, mat.transpose)
```

As you can see from running the test the code gives segmentation fault the second time I call the function `createMatrix`. This is my understanding:

1. I first create a pointer to a `struct Matrix`
2. I then pass this pointer as argument to `createMatrix`
3. I allocate a pointer to a 2D array
4. Create the 2D array
5. I assign the pointer to matrix-> nmatrix

Any idea? Is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the definition `void createMatrix(VALUE xxx, Matrix *mat)` and the use of `mat->nrows = …` etc inside the function, the calls to `createMatrix()` in `matmul_mul()` are wrong.

You have:

```
VALUE matmat_mul(VALUE self, VALUE matrixA, VALUE matrixB)
{
    int i,j;

    Matrix *matA;
    createMatrix(matrixA, matA);

    Matrix *matB;
    createMatrix(matrixB, matB);
```

You need:

```
VALUE matmat_mul(VALUE self, VALUE matrixA, VALUE matrixB)
{
    int i,j;

    Matrix matA;
    createMatrix(matrixA, &matA);

    Matrix matB;
    createMatrix(matrixB, &matB);
```

In the current code, you pass uninitialized pointers to `createMatrix()` and then assign to the 'random' memory that the pointers point at.  This seldom leads to happiness.  In the revised code, you have a pair of `Matrix` values and you pass the pointers to those to the `createMatrix()` function, which then fills in the details for you.